Installing shed anchor in rocky ground
I'm building a wooden platform for a gazebo to sit on top of and be secured to. I'm worried about high winds possibly knocking the gazebo over and it taking the platform with it, so I've decided to add a shed anchor to the platform. The only issue is my ground is really rocky, not boulders but enough softball sized rocks that I haven't been able to install an anchor.
My question is, can I dig a hole with a shovel to remove all the rocks and then repack it and install the anchor in that? Or am I missing some simple solution? Platform is 10x12 made with 2x6s on concrete deck blocks
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

What are you calling a "shed anchor?"

It's a large screw like device that screws into the ground and attaches to a shed to keep it from being moved

So a screw pile.  You aren't going to get the same anchoring effect by backfilling around a screw pile than if you'd screwed it into the virgin ground, but you might get some.  You might consider backfilling with concrete, or at least flowfill.

Concrete is a good idea actually, thank you for your help!
